# Simple Calculator stopped working after Compiled to .EXE file "Syntax error: Unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, syntax-error, eof

I'm new to coding. I would like to understand why something like this happens, and of couse how I could fix it.

When I run the .PY script, it works fine. But when I run it in CMD, or compile it to an EXE, it opens, or starts. I can fill in my first number. But when I want to fill in the operator, it stops working and gives me this error: `Syntax error: Unexpected EOF while parsing`.

Screenshot of the Error in the CMD:

[image: screenshot of the Error in the CMD]

The full code of this file:

```
i = 1
print("------------------CALCULATOR------------------")
print("-------- Valid operators:  +, -, /, * --------")
print("----------------------------------------------")
while i <= 2:
    num1 = float(input("Enter your first number: "))
    op = input("Enter the operator: ")
    num2 = float(input("Enter your second number: "))
    if op == "+":
        print(num1 + num2)
    elif op == "-":
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif op == "/":
        print(num1 / num2)
    elif op == "*":
        print(num1 * num2)
    else:
        print("You need to enter a valid operator!")

    more_calc = input("Do you want to do another calculation?\n---> ")
    if more_calc == "yes":
        print("----------------------------------------------\nOk!")
    elif more_calc == "no":
        i += 2

input("\n----------------------------------------------\nThank you for using my Calculator!\nPress enter to exit.\n----------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: `op = input("Enter the operator: ")` works fine for me (with Python 3.8.0). You would get that error if you're actually using Python 2.x though…and I think that's the problem. What does it display when you type `python --version`  by itself on the CMD line?

Comment: @martineau Thanks for your reply. What did i do wrong though? Did i accidentally compile my script with Python 2.x ? If so. How can i make sure i'm compiling with 3.x through CMD? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Python scripts aren't complied, they're interpreted by a Python interpreter. It sounds like a version 2 interpreter is installed on your system and associated with `.py` files. I would suggest downloading the latest Python 3 .EXE installer from `python.org` and running it.

Comment: @martineau Thanks again for your reply. I will look into this first thing after breakfast in about 10/13 hours from now. I will reply when i know more !

Comment: @martineau You are right! I don't know how. But i indeed had a 2.x version installed on my PC. And didn't set the pip 'PATH' in windows to my 3.8 version. Although now i'm having another issue, which is still open and going in other posts. This issue is fixed. So i thank you once again. Have a nice day !